# Wordpress country specific content

Tags: wordpress, plugins, country

Is it possible to make wordpress posts country specific?

For example, a blog under the url myblog.com. I have visitors in the UK and US, I want to create a post that only people from the US can see and vice versa. Would also require flexibility to filter with other countries

Answer (score 0):

This should be into http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. Anyway, I guess there are plenty of answers to this question already...

First, view this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26832/display-only-certain-posts-based-on-visitors-country

This 20$ plugin can also help you, but read carefully the features before buying!!

http://codecanyon.net/item/easy-translation-manager-for-wordpress/1187985